# EJB 2.1 subquery on JBoss AS7

Tags: jboss7.x, ejb-2.x, cmp

Good morning,

I'm migrating an EJB 2.1 project from JBoss AS5 to AS7, and I'm having some troubles. The project contains several EJB queries defined, and, some of them are not working, for example:

```
  <query>
    <query-method>
       <method-name>findByIdOwnershipMaxYear</method-name>
       <method-params>
         <method-param>java.lang.Long</method-param>
       </method-params>
    </query-method>
    <ejb-ql>SELECT OBJECT(o) FROM OwnershipHistory o WHERE o.id = ?1 and o.year = ( select max(oh.year) from OwnershipHistory oh where oh.id = ?1)</ejb-ql>
  </query>
```

All queries are declared on the *ejb-jar.xml* file of each module. When I start JBoss, the ones with subqueries (like above) always gives the org.jboss.as.cmp.ejbql.ParseException:

```
Encountered " "SELECT" "select "" at line 1, column 73.
Was expecting one of:
    "ABS" ...
    "LENGTH" ...
    "LOCATE" ...
    "SQRT" ...
    "MOD" ...
    "(" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    <INTEGER_LITERAL> ...
    <FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL> ...
    <NUMERIC_VALUED_PARAMETER> ...
    <NUMERIC_VALUED_PATH> ...
```

My doubt is, on previous versions, I could do the "subquery-supported" configuration in *standardjbosscmp-jdbc.xml* file; anyone knows if that is that still possible on AS7?

I took a look at the [datasource configuration guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/DataSource+configuration) and the [DD section](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Deployment+Descriptors+used+In+AS7.1), but so far I couldn't figure out where I can do that.

Sorry for any misspelling, English is not my native language

Thanks.